# How to Target Excel Solver's Value Cell

Tags: vba, excel, solver

With the code below, I am trying to use solver via Excel VBA. The reason for doing it is because I am using it for a large list of values and because I wish to target the value I want to solve for via a cell, however for some reason I am having issues with the `ValueOf:=SingleCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value, _` If I change it to `ValueOf:="-180"` (or any other number) it work fine. My goal is to link it to a cell, as the cell varies.

Info: `SingleCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value, _` has the value of -180

**EDIT 1**

```
Sub WatchlistSolver()

Dim SingleCell As Range

Range("N2").Select

'Need to link account value
Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Address, _
             MaxMinVal:=3, _
             ValueOf:=SingleCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value, _
             ByChange:=ActiveCell.Address
             SolverSolve userFinish:=True

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) = Int(ActiveCell.Value)

Loop Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = ""

End Sub
```

**EDIT 2**

```
Sub WatchlistSolver()

Range("N2").Select

'Need to link account value
Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Address, _
             MaxMinVal:=3, _
             ValueOf:=CStr(Range("O1").Value), _
             ByChange:=ActiveCell.Address
             SolverSolve userFinish:=True

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) = Int(ActiveCell.Value)

Loop Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UNTESTED**

Try changing:

```
ValueOf:=SingleCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value
```

into:

```
ValueOf:=CStr(SingleCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value)
```

That is because Solver does not appear to want a **number** for the parameter value, it wants the **string equivalent** of the number.

**EDIT#1:**

If you want to use a specific single cell on the Active worksheet then:

```
ValueOf:=CStr(Range("O2").Value)
```

Comment: That did not work, because it changes my active cell all the time (which is my fault. I am trying to set it to only one cell, but it does not work for some reason.
How can I set 'CStr(SingleCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value)' to reference a single cell on a worksheet: e.g. O2 ?